# How to correctly initialize and use a variable after a while loop

Tags: java, variables, while-loop

```
public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      int weaponNumber;
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(FILENAME);
      String line;
      while (fileScan.hasNextLine())
      {  
         line = fileScan.nextLine();
         Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
         weaponNumber = lineScan.nextInt();
      }
      intro();
      String[] weapons = menu(fileScan, weaponNumber);

RPSL.java:20: error: variable weaponNumber might not have been initialized
      String[] weapons = menu(fileScan, weaponNumber);
```

I am not sure why, but the compiler does not see the value I set for "weaponNumber" even though I initialized the variable before the while loop. How can i fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Because if `fileScan.hasNextLine()` is false, the `while` loop never gets entered and `weaponNumber` remains uninitialized.

Comment: You didn't initialize it, you just declared it. The compiler doesn't know what to print if the file is empty.

Comment: Ideally, this depends on what values can be allowed for `weaponNumber`. You should chose a value that is not allowed for `weaponNumber` for initialising it. After the loop execution, check for the validity of the value in `weaponNumber` and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are declaring a local variable on local method you must initialize that variable. Other wise java compiler will show eror. So please write
int weaponNumber =0; instead of just declaration

Answer (score 0):

weaponNumber is not initialized in your program. As I can see

`int weaponNumber;`

It's a declaration, not initialization.

In a while loop, what if fileScan don't have any next Line, then your program doesn't enter into the while loop. and weaponNumber remain uninitialized.

So,
`int weaponNumber = 0;`

do in this way, and if you are checking the value of weaponNumber in menu() method and you are allowing the 0 as a weaponNumber then define it as a -1.

`int weaponNumber =-1;`